# No latin URL - Greek characters in link

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite

I have an eshop in Greece and i want to configure its seo settings.

Its important for me to have greek characters in urls.

Althought, it automatically change them into latin characters.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In magento 1.9 it was done the following way: http://killerwhalesoft.com/blog/magento-unicode-url-key-products-categories-cms-pages/

It may help you to find which files need to be edited in 2.x - just make sure you do not edit core files, but put them in a module ;)